# Assessing feature importance without random forests

Tags: regression, feature-selection, random-forest, predictor, importance

What ways are there to assess variable (feature, covariate) importance in regression models, except for using random forests?

(For instance, using OLS regression, Bayesian parametric regression, etc.?)

Comment: There's no one way to answer this question.  Features are important in the context of a given question or application, not in and of themselves.  The naming of the random forest statistic as `feature importance` is, in my view, a great tragedy.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Yes, but if I use a regression model, how do I quantify how influential individual features are contributing to the regression model?

Comment: First you should ask yourself why you want to do that, and how you intend to use the information.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Input n number of covariates into a regression model. You should have techniques to see which parameters are affect the model, and which don't.

Comment: So you would like to do feature selection and end up with a model including a smaller number of features?  There are definitely techniques to do that, but they should not be interpreted as telling you anything about the "importance" of features.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Please feel free to edit the question above to reflect this.

Comment: The "bible" for feature importance are probably Ulrike Gromping's papers. She has an R module called RELAIMPO which implements her computationally intensive method. https://prof.beuth-hochschule.de/fileadmin/user/groemping/downloads/amstat07mayp139.pdf  One valid, "quick and dirty" heuristic is to run RF regressions and average the t-statistics for each parameter.

Comment: One popular approach to assess the importance of variables is Bayesian Model Averaging. Have a look at this nice [tutorial](http://bms.zeugner.eu/tutorials/bms.pdf) and the related [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BMS/index.html) in R. The basic idea is to estimate models with all possible combinations of covariates and to construct weighted averages across all models where posterior model probabilities are used as weights. For each variable this procedure yields a Posterior Inclusion Probability (PIP) which tells you how important this variable is. It's easy to implement.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, I edited your question considerably trying to highlight its focus and remove tangential information. If you think this has distorted your idea, you may undo (`rollback`) the edit.

Comment: You can assess the feature importance like in random forest only with other methods. You train your model on several subsets (cross-validation) of the whole data, change the data like in the VIMP method with permutation of the values in one variable and assess performance before and after permutation in the respective holdout data. The difference of the performance is your VIMP.